# Do cyclically presented groups of positive word length four relators satisfy the Tits Alternative?

Tags: gr.group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

I finished an MPhil a year ago that focused on the following question. I've moved on to a different area of group theory now, so I thought I'd ask it here.

> **Definition:** Let $w\in F_n$ for the free group $F_n$ on $\{x_i\mid i\in\overline{0,n-1}\}$ and $n\in \Bbb N$. A *cyclically presented group* is a group $G_n(w)$ with presentation
>
> $$P_n(w):=\langle x_0, \dots, x_{n-1}\mid w, \theta(w), \dots, \theta^{n-1}(w)\rangle,$$
>
> where $$\begin{align}\theta: F_n&\to F_n,\\ x_i&\mapsto x_{i+1\pmod{n}}.\end{align}$$

Let $w=x_0x_jx_kx_l$. This is a positive word of length four.

> **Definition:** A class $\mathcal{G}$ of groups satisfies the *Tits Alternative* if for any $G$ in $\mathcal G$ either $G$ has a free, non-abelian subgroup or $G$ has a solvable subgroup of finite index.

### The Question:

> Do cyclically presented groups of positive word length four relators satisfy the Tits Alternative?

---

My dissertation is available [here](https://www.academia.edu/102668826/On_Cyclically_Presented_Groups_of_Positive_Words_Length_Four_Relators) and [here](https://repository.essex.ac.uk/32610/). A paper by myself and my supervisor at the time, Prof. G. Williams, on the topic can be found [here](https://www.academia.edu/75510725/On_the_Tits_alternative_for_cyclically_presented_groups_with_length_four_positive_relators) and [here](https://repository.essex.ac.uk/32265/).

We found that, using mainly Bogley & Parker's paper [1], for

$$
(A)=\left\{\begin{array}{rlc}
2k &\equiv 0& \text{or}\\
2j &\equiv 2l&
\end{array}\right.
$$

$$(B)=\left\{\begin{array}{rlc}
k &\equiv 2j& \text{or}\\
k &\equiv 2l& \text{or}\\
2k&\equiv j+l& \text{or}\\
0&\equiv j+l&
\end{array}\right.$$

$$(C)=\left\{\begin{array}{rlc}
l&\equiv j+k& \text{or}\\
j &\equiv l+k&
\end{array}\right.$$

all modulo $n$, in all cases but when $(A)$ and $(C)$ are false while $(B)$ is true, the Tits Alternative holds. We gathered evidence in GAP for the remaining case up to $n=20$.

---

*References:*

[1] Bogley, W., A., Parker, F., W. (2018) Cyclically Presented Groups with Length Four
Positive Relators. *J. Group Theory 21(5) (2018).*

Answer (score 9):

When $j,|k-j|, |l-j|, |n-l|$ are all distinct, then the presentation complex is a $CAT(0)$ square complex, since the length of any path in the link of the vertex (which is a bipartite graph because of the positivity assumption) is at least 4. In this case, the Tits alternative follows from a result of [Sageev-Wise](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0405022). There are no finite subgroups in this case since the complex is $CAT(0)$ and hence aspherical, so their theorem applies.